# Sortable columns and admin like interface for tables/report in custom plugin?

Tags: wp-admin

We have wordpress admin interface for "all posts" list. Sortable column methods are available for "custom post type".

But can we not implement this type of `wp-admin` like interface with sortable columns in any reporting/table in our any custom plugin that show a tabular report or listings fetched from database?

Comment: As usual answer to "can we" is "yes". You can do anything with enough time and budget. Please try to focus your question on more specific details of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own class extending [`WP_List_Table`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table).

To get a point where start look how Wordpress itself use that class for posts, creating the [`WP_Posts_List_Table`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php) class.